# Dropdown selected value not changing color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the color of the selected value in the dropdown. I can see color is different for each value but when I select it change it back to black.

```css
.appt-status select option[value="0"] {
    color: #3EA47B;
}

.appt-status option[value="1"] {
    color: #3EA47B
}

.appt-status option[value="2"] {
    color: #FF0000;
}

.appt-status option[value="3"] {
    color: #FFA927;
}
```

```html
  <select class="form-control appt-status" data-bind="value: confirmationStatus, event:{ change: $parent.statusChanged}" >
                <option data-icon="" class="status-list" value="1" > Confirmed</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="2" >Reschedule</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="3" >Pending</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="0" >Not opted-in</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this working example

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select");
const options = Array.from(select.children);

// MAKE SURE TO KEEP THE COLOR CONSISTENT EVEN AFTER RELOAD
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  options.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.selected) {
      select.style.color = getComputedStyle(option).color
    }
  });
})

select.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  options.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.selected) {
      select.style.color = getComputedStyle(option).color
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KunalTanwar/normalize/css/normalize.inter.min.css";
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.appt-status option[value="0"] {
  color: #3ea47b;
}

.appt-status option[value="1"] {
  color: #3ea47b;
}

.appt-status option[value="2"] {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.appt-status option[value="3"] {
  color: #ffa927;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control appt-status" data-bind="value: confirmationStatus, event:{ change: $parent.statusChanged}">
  <option data-icon="" class="status-list" value="1"> Confirmed</option>
  <option class="status-list" value="2">Reschedule</option>
  <option class="status-list" value="3">Pending</option>
  <option class="status-list" value="0">Not opted-in</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can see it working here but not in my code base. I copied and pasted the js code but it did not work.

Comment: because you need to change few things selecting `.class` I generally selected by `tagNames` change it with your specified `class names` or `ids`.